# Cierre de sesión con Hibernate y Spring

Tags: mysql, java, spring, hibernate

Quiero saber ¿Cómo cerrar la sesión hibernate, si estoy manejando la transacción con Spring 4.x?.

### Modelo

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
@Entity
@Table(name="EGRESOS")
public class Egreso {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    @Temporal (TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="fecha")
    private Date fecha;
    @Column(name="importe")
    private Double importe;
    @Column(name="detalle")
    private String detalle;

    public Egreso() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

//all getters and setters
```

### Persistencia

```
public abstract class CustomHibernateSupport<T> extends HibernateDaoSupport implements IGenericDAO<T> {
    private Class<T> persistentClass;
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "deprecation" })
    public CustomHibernateSupport() {
        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        this.sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure() // configures
                                                                // settings from
                                                                // hibernate.cfg.xml
        .buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        getHibernateTemplate().setCacheQueries(true);
    }

    public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
        return persistentClass;
    }

    public void setPersistentClass(Class<T> persistentClass) {
        this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
    }

    public void insert(T entity) {
        getHibernateTemplate().save(entity);
    }

    public void delete(T entity) {
        getHibernateTemplate().delete(entity);    
    }

    public void update(T entity){
        getHibernateTemplate().update(entity);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findAll() {
        Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(getPersistentClass());

        return cr.list();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T findById(Long id) {
        Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria criteria= session.createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
                 criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id",id));                 
        return (T) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findByDate(Date date) {
        System.out.println(date);
        Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria criteria= session.createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
                 criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("fecha",date));

        return  criteria.list();
    }
}
```

### Servicio

```
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
public boolean cargarGasto(GastosRequestDTO nuevo){
    Egreso e = new Egreso();
    try{
            e.setDetalle(nuevo.getDetalle());
            e.setFecha(nuevo.getFecha());
            e.setImporte(nuevo.getImporte());
            egreso.insert(e);
            log.info("se inserto correctamente el nuevo gasto ID: "+ e.getId());
            return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        log.error(Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(ex));
        log.error("No se pudo insertar gasto ");
    }
    return false;
}
```

### Controlador

```
public void cargarGasto() {
        GastosRequestDTO nuevoGasto = new GastosRequestDTO();
        nuevoGasto.setFecha(fecha);
        nuevoGasto.setDetalle(descripcion);
        nuevoGasto.setImporte(importe);
        if (hotel.cargarGastos(nuevoGasto)) {
            obtenerBalance();
            setImporte(null);
            setDescripcion(null);

    }
}
```

### ApplicattionContex.xml

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="ar.com.as.hotel"/>
<bean id="recordDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    lazy-init="true" destroy-method="close">

    <property name="driverClass" value="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" />

    <!-- CHANGE THE DATABASE CONNECTION-->
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/hotelTest"/>        
    <property name="user" value="********" />
    <property name="password" value="********" />
    <!-- ***************************************** -->

    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>./WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="recordDataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

### Hibernate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/hotel***</property>
        <property name="connection.username">******</property>
        <property name="connection.password">******</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="connection.autocommit">false</property>

<!--        <mapping resource="Cliente.hbm.xml" /> -->

        <mapping class="ar.com.as.hotel.modelo.Ingreso" ></mapping>
        <mapping class="ar.com.as.hotel.modelo.Precio"></mapping>
        <mapping class="ar.com.as.hotel.modelo.Habitacion"></mapping>
        <mapping class="ar.com.as.hotel.modelo.Temporada"></mapping>
        <mapping class="ar.com.as.hotel.modelo.Egreso"></mapping>


        <!-- List of XML mapping files -->

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 10):

La sesión se va a cerrar sola. Spring Transaction la va a manejar por ti. Solo asegúrate que los métodos que necesiten conectividad a la base de datos y utilicen Hibernate estén anotados correctamente con `@Transactional` o que estén configurados vía xml.

Comment: Eso es lo que yo pensaba Luiggi, pero por alguna razón no cierra. Hay forma de forzar el cierre ?

Comment: Como estas llamando al metodo cargarGasto?

Comment: Desde el controlador, llamo a ese metodo  ahi pego la llamada

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y muestra el codigo. Asegurate tambien de haber agregado el soporte de transaccionabilidad en el xml de configuration o via anotacion si todo es programatico. Seria genial si tambirn agregas la configuracion de spring en el proyecto.

Comment: Creo que ahí quedó más clara la edición

Comment: Disculpa la demora. Segun veo, tienes 2 configuraciones para la conexion en hibernate: una mediante el bean recordDataSource y otra en hibernate.cfg.xml. Elimina la del archivo de configuracion de Hibernate y deja que Spring se haga cargo de crear el session factory para Hibernate.

Comment: Bueno gracias por el consejo Luiggi, ya lo pruebo , Una pregunta más : el mapeo lo realiza solo  Spring , si yo borro ese archivo hibernate.xml. Gracias

Comment: No, no lo borres. En ese archivo debes colocar el mapeo de clases que manejara Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Como lo veo es mas que nada un problema de tu configuración, realmente trata de no mezclar peras con manzanas.

Te puedo decri que el archivo `Hibernate.xml` esta de mas ya que ahora tienes un archivo de configuración con Spring el cual te sirve para lo mismo.

Lo mejor es que le digas a Spring que tus entidades se encuentran en tal paquete y te cree la unidad de persistencia que necesitas, asi ya no tendras que estar agregando cada una de las entidades que generes al archivo.

Este es un ejemplo.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.todo.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.todo" />
```

Aquí una pregunta para evitar el archivo `persistence.xml` que es el equivalente a tu archivo de Hibernate.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381943/how-to-configure-spring-without-persistence-xml

Y aquí un proyecto con la configuración ya hecha

https://github.com/ripper2hl/angular-todo